# Locate specfic word from a big string

Tags: c#, regex

If you have the three different wordd `"candy3_ string box number"`, `"ddcandy3_ string box number"` and "`ff candy3_ string box number"` and you want to locate if the word "candy3_string" exist in the wordd.

How should I write the regex in c#?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to see if the word exists or get it's position? And are you abolutely sure you want to use a regex? Is `"candy3_ string"` the same as  `"candy3_string"`?

Answer (score 2):

To check if it *exist* use `.Contains("candy3_string");`

And to get it's *position* `.IndexOf("candy3_string");`